# If $(G,\cdot)$ and $(G,+)$ are groups, are they always isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

It is possible for a group to have alternative operation. For example, consider the following operations on $\mathbb{Z}^2$: $(x_1,y_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2+x_1x_2)$ and $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$. Both $(\mathbb{Z}^2,\cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}^2,+)$ are groups, and I know that they are isomorphic. However, is it true that in general, a group is isomorphic to itself under an alternative operation? ie, if $(G,\cdot)$ and $(G,+)$ are groups, are they always isomorphic? I can't think of an counterexample.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. There are many examples of groups that have the same size and yet are not isomorphic. Take any such pair $G, H$ and then use your favorite bijection to rewrite elements of $H$ as elements of $G$.

Comment: You haven't looked very hard. The cyclic group of order 6 is not isomorphic to the symmetry group of a triangle, which also has order 6.

Comment: The elements have to be the same, though, @RobArthan; they're defined differently in that example.

Comment: @Shaun: the "names" of the elements of a group are irrelevant in this context. It is a trivial exercise to get two non-isomorphic groups on a given 6-element set proceeding as per my comment.

Comment: Trivial, or simply familiar, @RobArthan?

Comment: Trivial, once you've taken the trouble to classify groups of small finite orders, which is an easy exercise up to order $6$.

Comment: I think you're putting the cart before the horse there, @RobArthan.

Comment: @Shaun: let's agree to differ rather than bicker on this, please.

Comment: Agreed, @RobArthan :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Think of $G=\{e,a,b,c\}$ as a set.

Define

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\star & e & a & b & c\\
\hline
e & e & a & b & c\\
a & a & b & c & e\\
b & b & c & e & a\\
c & c & e & a & b
\end{array}.$$

Then $(G,\star)\cong \Bbb Z_4$.

Define

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\ast &
    e & a & b & c\\
\hline
e & e & a & b & c\\
a & a & e & c & b \\
b & b & c & e & a\\
c & c & b & a & e
\end{array}.$$

Then $(G,\ast)\cong \Bbb Z_2^2$.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your question, I think you mean if a **set** $S$ admits two group operations must they be isomorphic? That is clearer than considering a "group to have an alternate operation".  In that case there are simple counterexamples, e.g. a set with 4 elements admits two distinct group structures: one is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4$ and the other to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$. While writing this the above equivalent answer was posted.

Comment: yes, I meant the set